# Selling per-node access without creating two entities

Tags: 7, commerce

I want to create a Pay-per-view site under Drupal.

I followed [the instructions of Commerce guys](https://commerceguys.com/blog/selling-node-access-drupal-commerce), which combines the use of [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and [Content access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access).

But this solution means creating two entities: a product display + the paying article. It raises several problems: two nodes with the same name, two nodes as we can comment...

I would thus want only one node, with a visible teaser before purchase, then all the text after purchase.

My question : how to selling per-node access without creating two entities ?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you want to display the content to your customers. For example, you could show a teaser of the content page via Views. Access to the full content page could be contingent on node access implemented via the Content Access module. You then just have to figure out how to display to the customer which articles they have full access to - for example, a "Purchased articles" View that shows all fully accessible articles using a node access filter.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your help. I'm not sure to understand: it is possible with View to show a teaser of a paying contents even if the users have no access to these paying contents? Otherwise, there are several problems, for example, to comment the paying contents: how to show in the product display the comments of the contents paying that he references? Generally speaking, it does not "weigh down" the site?

Comment: For the display : he will be the following one: the user sees the paying contents, in this case only his teaser, then the price and "add to cart", he buys it, and then sees the contents paying in its entirety.

Comment: Yes, with Views you can bypass node access to show a teaser of all of these nodes.

Comment: Thank you, I found how to make, [for those whom that interests](https://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/permissions/restrict/views). But that does not answer the problem of the double nodes...

Comment: Yes it does. You can have one node with a teaser that shows in the publicly available view. A link to the full node page could be on a view that actually is filtered by node access. One node.

Comment: Really sorry but i do not understand. You mean that it is possible to have the product display and the premium content in the same page with views, is it good? The progress would be the following one: 1/ a view lists paying articles, with teaser, 2/ the user clicks the article of his choice, he arrives on the page of the article, he sees: the teaser, the price / add to cart, and 3/ once bought he sees all the article? In summary, you mean : to merge product display and premium content with views?